# How to stop multiple reads of an RFID card

Tags: arduino, rfid

I'm using an 125Khz RFID module RDM6300 with arduino nano.
While the card is near the RFID reader the loop will read the card multiple times. I want it to read only once while the card is near the reader then read it again if a new connection is being made.
 *This code is not writen by me, this is the source:
https://github.com/Wookai/arduino-rfid

```
    // define constants for pins
//int SUCCESS = 10;
//int ERROR = 13;

// variables to keep state
int readVal = 0; // individual character read from serial
unsigned int readData[10]; // data read from serial
int counter = -1; // counter to keep position in the buffer
char tagId[11]; // final tag ID converted to a string

char* authorizedTags[4]; // array to hold the list of authorized tags

// fills the list of authorzied tags
void initAuthorizedTags() {
  // add your own tag IDs here
  authorizedTags[0] = "0400680B85";
  authorizedTags[1] = "0400063EB9";
  authorizedTags[2] = "040004F3F5";
  authorizedTags[3] = "04006813AB";
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // pinMode(SUCCESS, OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(ERROR, OUTPUT);
  initAuthorizedTags();
}

// check if the tag ID we just read is any of the authorized tags
int checkTag() {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    if (strcmp(authorizedTags[i], tagId) == 0) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

// convert the int values read from serial to ASCII chars
void parseTag() {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    tagId[i] = readData[i];
  }
  tagId[10] = 0;
}

// once a whole tag is read, process it
void processTag() {
  // convert id to a string
  parseTag();

  // print it
  printTag();

  // check if the tag is authorized
  if (checkTag() == 1) {
    tagSuccess(); // if so, perform an action (blink a led, open a door, etc...)
  } else {
    tagFailed(); // otherwise, inform user of failure
  }
}

void printTag() {
  Serial.print("Tag value: ");
  Serial.println(tagId);
}

// perform an action when an authorized tag was read
void tagSuccess() {
  Serial.println("Tag authorized.");

  // here, we simply turn on the success LED for 2s
  // digitalWrite(SUCCESS, HIGH);
  //digitalWrite(ERROR, LOW);
  // delay(2000);
}

// inform the user that the tag is not authorized
void tagFailed() {
  Serial.println("Unauthorized access!");

  //digitalWrite(SUCCESS, LOW);
  // digitalWrite(ERROR, HIGH);
  // delay(2000);
}

// this function clears the rest of data on the serial, to prevent multiple scans
void clearSerial() {
  while (Serial.read() >= 0) {
    ; // do nothing
  }
}

void loop() {
  // turn LEDs off
  // digitalWrite(SUCCESS, LOW);
  //  digitalWrite(ERROR, LOW);

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    readVal = Serial.read();

    // a "2" signals the beginning of a tag
    if (readVal == 2) {
      counter = 0; // start reading
    }
    // a "3" signals the end of a tag
    else if (readVal == 3) {
      // process the tag we just read
      processTag();

      // clear serial to prevent multiple reads
      clearSerial();

      // reset reading state
      counter = -1;
    }
    // if we are in the middle of reading a tag
    else if (counter >= 0) {
      // save valuee
      readData[counter] = readVal;

      // increment counter
      ++counter;

    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Thank you for your answers. I tried to accept the multiple reads and print only one but it keeps printing "already read" instead of reading the card first time, this is the code:

```
void printTag() {
  if(strcmp(tagId,previous)==1){
  strcpy(previous, tagId);

  Serial.print("Tag value: ");
  Serial.println(tagId);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print("already read");
  }

}
```

I also tried to put the delay after end of tag but it still reads the card multiple times.

I tried another code, it still reads the tag multiple times.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// RFID  | Nano
// Pin 1 | D2
// Pin 2 | D3
SoftwareSerial Rfid = SoftwareSerial(2,3);
int timer=0;
int reference = 1000;
int card_status = 0;
void setup() {
  // Serial Monitor to see results on the computer
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Communication to the RFID reader
  Rfid.begin(9600);
}

void read() {
  // check, if any data is available

    // as long as there is data available...
    while(Rfid.available() > 0 ){
      // read a byte
      int r = Rfid.read();
      // print it to the serial monitor
      Serial.print(r, DEC);
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
    // linebreak
    Serial.println();
  timer=0;
}

void loop()
{
 if((Rfid.available() > 0 ) && (card_status == 0) )
 {
 read();
 }
 if((!Rfid.available() > 0 ) && (card_status == 1) )
 {
  card_status=0;
 }
}
```

I'm sorry for the late response. I forgot about this topic.

I solved the problem by making the arduino wait for a response after writing the RFID code for the frist time. 
I was able to do that because my arduino was sending the code to a C# application via serial port.

Here is how it works: the arduino prints the RFID code on the serial, from there it is picked up by the C# application which searches a database to see if the code is stored there. Depending on the result, the application prints a character('y' or 'n') which is picked up by the arduino. Depending on the character recieved, the arduino lights up a led ( green or red) and makes a noise. Now a new RFID reading can be made.

Here is the code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "RDM6300.h"

SoftwareSerial rdm_serial(8, 9);
RDM6300<SoftwareSerial> rdm(&rdm_serial);
String comanda;
char c="";

int led_verde = 2;
int led_rosu = 7;
int buzzer = 12;
int i;

void buzz(int n = 1)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    delay(200);
  }
}

void ledVerde()
{
  digitalWrite(led_verde, HIGH);
  buzz(1);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(led_verde, LOW);
}

void ledRosu()
{
  digitalWrite(led_rosu, HIGH);
  buzz(3);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(led_rosu, LOW);
}


void setup()
{
  pinMode(led_verde, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_rosu, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led_verde, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led_rosu, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{

  static unsigned long long last_id = 0;
  last_id = rdm.read();
    rdm.print_int64(last_id);
    Serial.println();

  rdm_serial.end();
  Serial.flush();
  while(!Serial.available());
   c=Serial.read();

  if(c=='y')
  {
  ledVerde();
  c="";
  }
 if(c=='n')
  {
    ledRosu();
  }

  Serial.flush();
  last_id="";
  c="";
  rdm_serial.begin(9600);
}
```

You can find the RDM6300 library here: https://github.com/arliones/RDM6300-Arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I guess what you want is a edge trigger instead of level trigger with time limit.

> For example, you may prefer to read a RFID card when it firstly comes near to the antenna, once only; when it keeps to contact the antenna, still take no more actions. When you remove the card and place it again near to the antenna, the MCU starts to read the card again.
>
> If so, the following code could be for your reference. What I have done is just to add 1 more flag to keep checking the `card_status` before checking if a RFID card comes near to the antenna.

```
int card_status = 0; //0:readable; 1:not-readable

if ( (Serial.available() > 0) && (card_status == 0) ) { 
    card_status = 1; //disable to read card after exit this loop 
    //your code, a card is near to the antenna, try to read it. 
    
    readVal = Serial.read(); 
    
    if (readVal == 2) { 
        counter = 0; // start reading 
    } else if (readVal == 3) { 
        processTag(); 
        clearSerial(); 
        counter = -1; 
    } else if (counter >= 0) { 
        readData[counter] = readVal; 
        ++counter; 
    } 
    
}
```

> reset the card status when no RFID signal comes in && card status is true,

```
if ( (!(Serial.available() > 0)) && (card_status == 1) ) { 
    card_status = 0; //enable to read card again
    //no signal, no card is near to the antenna.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried your method but it keeps reading the tag multiple times.  this is the code: if ( (Serial.available() > 0) && (card_status == 0) ) {
    
     card_status = 1;
    readVal = Serial.read();

    
    if (readVal == 2) {
      counter = 0; // start reading
    }
    
    else if (readVal == 3) {
      
      processTag();
      

     
      clearSerial();

      
      counter = -1;
    }
   
    else if (counter >= 0) {
      
      readData[counter] = readVal;
      ++counter;
     
    }
  }
  else
  {
    card_status = 0;
  }

Comment: `if ( (Serial.available() > 0) && (card_status == 0) ) { 
 card_status = 1; 
 readVal = Serial.read(); 
 
 if (readVal == 2) { 
  counter = 0; // start reading 
 } else if (readVal == 3) { 
  processTag(); 
  clearSerial(); 
  counter = -1; 
 } else if (counter >= 0) { 
  readData[counter] = readVal; 
  ++counter; 
 } 
 
} 

//reset the card status when no RFID signal comes in && card status is true,
if ( (!(Serial.available() > 0)) && (card_status == 1) ) { 
 card_status = 0; 
}`

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer above, see if this could help you. Also, I recommend you add some LED on/off in your code to show the status in order to verify your thought.

Comment: I tried this but now it doesn't print anything. I also tried a different code and used the same aproach to stop multiple reads, but it just keeps reading the tag multiple times. I edited my question and put the code there. Could this be a problem with my arduino board / rfid module?

Comment: A good try! I suggest you keep to debug by the latest code. I read your code, seemly you forgot to add `card_status=1;` when you started to read the RFID tag, right?

Answer (score 1):

Long time passed the original question, but maybe my answer would be useful for future visitors.

The RDM6300 works by:

1. automatically reading the data, and then
2. your code transfers the read data to the buffer for further processing.

Imagine it as a Baggage carousel in the airport. There are multiple luggage (data) on the carousel (reader), and you pick them one by one (transferring to buffer).

So, the problem of multiple reads, is that you have got read data in the reader (luggage on the carousel), that your code is gradually transferring them to the buffer (picking the luggage up).

In our example, if you don't like to collect all luggage, you can ask someone to take some of them, before they reach to you.

The below code does this. While you have data in the reader (the card is near to the reader), it transfers data from reader to buffer and then zeros all of them in the buffer:

First, place this code before "void setup()":

```
boolean multipleRead = false;
```

This defines a false/true variable to tell if this is the first time you are reading the tag (false), or it's being read multiple times (true).

Then, put this one at the end of the code block that shows the tag is fully read. If you are using Michael Schoeffler's library for your RDM6300/630 RFID, put it after "else if (ssvalue == 3) {":

```
 multipleRead = true;
```

It change the variable to true, when your tag is read. That tells the program that your first read is done and the next upcoming read(s) would be "multiple read" and you don't want them.

Then put this at the end of the RFID reader code (if your RFID code is under void loop (), put the below code just after "void loop (){":

```
if (multipleRead) {
  while (ssrfid.available() > 0) {
    int ssvalue = ssrfid.read(); // read
    if (ssvalue == -1) { // no data was read
      break;
    }
  }
  for (int x = 0; x < 14; x++)
  {
    buffer[x] = 0;
  }
  multipleRead = false;
}
```

It empties the reader and then zeros the buffer, while there is a card nearby. When you move the card away, multipleRead value would turn to false, which let another RFID reading loop to initiate.

Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a delay (e.g. `delay(2000)`) after reading the (end of tag). A delay of (say) 2 seconds will allow the user to move the card far enough away from the reader. Note that `delay` is a blocking command which might not suit your purposes, in which case you could be looking at using the `millis` count to activate/deactivate the `Serial.read`.

Another option is to accept the multiple reads, but keep a state of which card has been read. If the new card number is the same as the old card number (within a reasonable timeframe) then just ignore.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried to accept the multiple reads and print only one but it keeps printing "already read" instead of reading the card first time, I edited my question and added the code.

Comment: @Roro Yes I did solve it. I edited my question and added the solution. See if it suits your needs.